# How can I use kartograph.js?

Tags: javascript, python, svg, kartograph

Is there anyone who has used the library kartograph.js and 'kartograph.py'?
Do you know if I need 'kartograph.py' to be able to run?How can I use the library 'kartograph.py' without installing python? Because I have a problem with 'kartograph.js' when I build the 'BBOX' in the 'kartograph.js'

The error in the kartograph.js :

```
.... 
if (height === 0) height = width * .5;
        alert(width);
        me.viewport = new kartograph.BBox(0, 0, width, height);
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
        me.paper = me.createSVGLayer();
        me.markers = [];
        me.pathById = {};
        me.container.addClass('kartograph');
    }
....
```

Thank you for your help

The HTML page. The error come when I build $K.map

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GEOFRANCE</title>
    <link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script/js/script.min.js"></script>
```

```
  $script(['/script/js/jquery.min.js','/script/js/raphael.min.js', '/script/js/kartograph.js', '/script/js/chroma.min.js'], 'kartograph');

  $script(['/script/js/jquery.qtip.min.js'], 'qtip');
```

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/jquery.qtip.css">    
<script type="text/javascript">

$script.ready(['kartograph', 'qtip'], function () {

    $(function () {
        var map,
            colorscale,
            dep_data = {},
            w = $('#map').parent().width();
        $.fn.qtip.defaults.style.classes = 'ui-tooltip-bootstrap';
        $.fn.qtip.defaults.style.def = false;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'departments.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("test : " + w);

                $.each(data, function (i, r) {
                    dep_data[r.id] = r;

                })


                map = $K.map('#map', w, w);

                alert("test2 : " +w);
                map.loadMap('france-departments.svg', function () {
                    map.addLayer('departments', {
                        titles: function (d) { return d.id },
                        styles: {
                            stroke: '0.5px'
                        },
                        tooltips: function (d) {
                            return [d.name, dep_data[d.id].density + '/km<sup>2</sup>'];
                        }
                    });
                    updateMap();
                });
            }
        });

        /*
        * update map colors
        */
        function updateMap() {
            var prop = 'density', // $('.measure.btn-custom').data('value'),
                scale = 'quantiles', // $('.scale.btn-custom').data('value'),
                colors = $('#colors').get(0).value;

            colorscale = new chroma.ColorScale({
                colors: chroma.brewer[colors],
                limits: chroma.limits(dep_data, scale, 7, prop)
            });
            map.getLayer('departments').style({
                fill: function (d) {
                    return colorscale.getColor(dep_data[d.id][prop]);
                }
            });

        }

        // init user interface
        $('.btn').click(function (event) {
            var tgt = $(event.target), par = tgt.parent();
            $('.btn', par).removeClass('btn-custom');
            tgt.addClass('btn-custom');
            updateMap();
        });

        $('#colors').change(updateMap);
        $('#colors').keyup(updateMap);

    });

});
</script>

<div id="map">
</div>

</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the map you're going to use with kartograph.py, so this directly answers your next question, yes, you need to install Python to use it. You can't run something written in Python without the Python interpreter.

I'm not really sure where did you read about that BBox method, but the docs say something way different: http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.js/

Comment: Thank you. So, if I want to use kartograph for my website, I need Python Interpreter on my server?

Comment: No, according to docs, you only need to generate a map using the .py. Once generated, you're free to use only the .js with the generated map.

Comment: So I don't understand. I am using a SVG map generated by kartograph.py. The BBox method is used in kartograph.js and it's on the BBox method that I have an error

Comment: Could you make a small jsfiddle? Or maybe paste some more code and the error you're getting?

Comment: I have a problem on the line : map = $K.map('#map', w, w);

Comment: Can you use firebug or chrome dev tools and edit your question posting the actual error you're getting?

Comment: if (height === 0) height = width * .5;
            alert(width);
            me.viewport = new kartograph.BBox(0, 0, width, height);
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
            me.paper = me.createSVGLayer();
            me.markers = [];
            me.pathById = {};
            me.container.addClass('kartograph');
        }

Comment: The error log you're posting doesn't match with the code from your question. Please show the exact code that's causing the error.

Comment: I change the question. The error come when I build $K.map used in the kartograph.js

Comment: AS I said before, I don't know where are you reading from, but BBox is not a method of that library (or at least I can't see it anywhere). Please read the docs.

Comment: I find my error. Thank you very much for your help. I used the library kartograph.js in the "_build" folder